# Fiware: Broken integration with Knowage

Tags: hdfs, fiware, fiware-cygnus, fiware-knowage, knowage

Since several days I'm trying to implement my solution based on different fiware components with Knowage platform. What I'm trying to do is simply connect Knowage to HDFS to perform simple queries on the data that is stored via Cygnus. I managed to set up the DataSource correctly and the connection test is ok, but when I try to query creating my DataSet I keep getting the error "Method not supported". I have already found and solved several problems related to missing Jar and I have done manually inserting them, but this last error continues to appear without offering a way out.
I'm currently using Knowage 7.2 CE with docker, image taken from dockerhub. I've tried different versions, for example 8 and 8.1, but they all lead to the same error. Even an installation on Windows 10 has the same errors.
The HDFS database was deployed via the Hortonworks container via the official image.
I have been stuck on this issue for several days now, is anyone able to help me?

Comment: Unless you can create a [reproducible snippet of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then Stack Overflow as a Q+A site is probably not the right forum to open this issue. I would suggest you try and engage the Knowage team directly by raising an issue on their [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/KnowageLabs/Knowage-Server)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.